# Import Error for module Datastax Spark Cassandra Connector

Tags: python, pyspark, cassandra, spark-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

I tried running the python spark-shell using the below command:

```
 bin/pyspark --packages datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:1.5.0-RC1-s_2.11,org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka_2.10:1.6.0
```

The output of the following command shows that it was able it find the spark-cassandra-connector package:

```
resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent;1.0
   confs: [default]
   found datastax#spark-cassandra-connector;1.5.0-RC1-s_2.11 in spark-packages
   found org.apache.cassandra#cassandra-clientutil;2.2.2 in central
   found com.datastax.cassandra#cassandra-driver-core;3.0.0-rc1 in central
   found io.netty#netty-handler;4.0.33.Final in central
   found io.netty#netty-buffer;4.0.33.Final in central
   found io.netty#netty-common;4.0.33.Final in central
```

But when I try to import the package using any of the below commands, I get Import Error:

```
from com.datastax import *
from com.datastax.spark.connector import *
```

Output:

```
ImportError: No module named com.datastax
ImportError: No module named com.datastax.spark.connector
```

Can anyone please suggest what is going wrong here ?

Comment: hello,how did you solve this problem ? please say me

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Cassandra Connector doesn't a single line of Python code not to mention weirdly named Python modules. Python interoperability is achieved using Data Sources API which can be used without any additional imports.

```
sqlContext.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(...).load(...)
```

Even if it did `--packages` are used only to distribute JVM dependencies. External dependencies (Python, R) have to distributed or installed dependently for example using `PyFiles`.